# Using hashtag in URL to perform actions?

Tags: jquery, tags

Currently have something like so :

```
$anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");

if ($anchor == 'Home'){
       --perform some actions--
}
```

While this works... it only works when the page is initially accessed.  In other words, if I am at test.html and manually add #Home to the url in the browser nothing will happen unless I refresh the page.  Is there a way to make this so it is always checking the hashtag rather than just initially on page load?  I remember there was a .live or something I used once which seemed to do something similar to what I am looking for.

EDIT :

```
var $zproductclick = jQuery.noConflict();
$zproductclick('a').live('click', function(event){ 

    if ((window.location.hash.replace("#", "")) == 'home'){
       $zproductclick(".homeproduct").add(".networkproduct").add(".parentalproduct").add(".allproduct").hide();
       $zproductclick(".homeproduct").add(".allproduct").fadeIn(1000);
       $zproductclick("#prodall").add("#prodnet").add("#prodparent").removeClass("active");
       $zproductclick("#prodhome").addClass("active");
       $zproductclick("#prodversion").removeClass("prodselectno").addClass("prodselect");
    }

})
```

Why do I have to click twice for the actions to occur? It seems it reads the old hash instead of the one immediately after clicking.

Comment: Don't really need one... all I need is a way to perform functions if the hashtag is changed... at its current state it only works on initial page load.  I need it to change whenever the hash is changed. In other words the actions within the 'if' could be anything.

Comment: There is a hashchange event, however it isn't implemented in all browsers. For the browsers that don't support it, you'll need a setInterval that continuously checks for the hash to change.

Comment: I think I have a solution...I just gotta eat real quick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** For IE

[**Working Example**](http://videsignz.com/hash2.html#changeme)

**JQuery**

```
var x = window.location.href;

    function checkhash(){
        x = window.location.href;
        $('#results').html(x); //Just to show the results, Delete in your code
        //Put your functions here....       
        window.setTimeout(checkhash, 1);
    }

checkhash();
```

Comment: @user756659 Works in IE now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add event on each link. Thats all.

```
$('a').on('click', function(event){ /* check hash tag here */ })
```

By default, if link has hash tag it will go to that id if it exists, if not, it will go to page top. So if it matches anything call *event.preventDefault();*

Comment: Using your click method - it works, but I have to click twice for the actions to work...

    var $zproductclick = jQuery.noConflict();
$zproductclick('a').live('click', function(event){ 

 if ((window.location.hash.replace("#", "")) == 'home'){
     $zproductclick(".homeproduct").add(".networkproduct").add(".parentalproduct").add(".allproduct").hide();
     $zproductclick("#prodhome").addClass("active");
     $zproductclick("#prodversion").removeClass("prodselectno").addClass("prodselect");
 }
    })

Comment: Yes, first time it sets hashtag, next time it cecks it. So you have to check the actual href attribute, not what browser has. So like this you will get yout hashtag: var hashtag = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];